# JS doesn't work on Safari on mobile devices only, can't replicate in Safari Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, safari

Looking for ideas on how to debug instances where JS doesn't work on Safari mobile, works fine on desktop, and then in desktop when I open the Safari console and run the page again using Safari-iOS 9.3-iPhone (which is the version people have had issues on) on a mobile screen it still is working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use can use safari remote debug, you can find a detail steps online